# pentaho merge rows diff with using text file inputs

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a text file that I need to load into a database... I used merge rows(diff)...
I compared the text file input with table input step..  i used sorted merge for sorting columns for both text file input and table input steps.. and i used merge rows(diff) step followed by Synchronize after merge... My problem is if i run my job first time its inserting the text file data to database.. and the second time also its inserting same rows again into the database... Can any one please help me what mistake i did..

Comment: Could you please post your transform. Even just a screen shot.

Comment: is it possible to del existing data and then insert new data?

Comment: No.. only i should do insert and update while using merge rows(diff)...

Answer (score 1):

use " Insert / Update " step in your transformation.. so it will avoid your duplication problem.

[Insert/update Description](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Insert+-+Update)

Comment: i used insert/update step.. but its taking to run 1 hour.. i want reduce the running time.. then only i used merge rows(diff)...

Comment: But the documentation of Merge Diff say's that a "changed" label will be displayed in the update case http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Synchronize+after+merge, but it throws me a duplicated row, first a "deleted" then a "new". 
I need only one row with the "changed" label

Comment: @mariowise don't know your scenario but i can say you can use unique raw step in-between to avoid your duplication.
if you only want to update new lable just use ascending/descending and then use unique raws steps so your problem will be solved.